# Hard problem : Prove that $\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Big)\Big)<\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: inequality, power-series, gamma-function, constants

It's a problem that I can't solve it's :

> > $$\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Big)\Big)<\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

You have the difference [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%280.5%28gamma%280.5gamma%280.5%29%29%29%29-pi%C2%B2%2F6).

What I know :

We have $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\Gamma\Big(\frac{-3}{2}\Big)\Gamma^3\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)$$

Unfortunately we have a negative term so we cannot use the fact that  the gamma function is a strictly logarithmically convex function .

I have tried furthermore power series we have (see wiki page on Gamma function) :

$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\Big)z+O(z^2)$$

But it's not sufficient and with more terms it's more delicate .

Finally I have tried Gautschi's inequality without success .

Now I think it's impossible to do it by hand and if someone do that I will open a bounty for him .

Any helps is greatly appreciated...

...Thanks a lot for all your contributions.

### Update :

Recalling that :

$$\psi'(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Where $\psi(x)$ is the Digamma function .

We study the following function :

$$f(x)=\psi'(x)-\Gamma\Big(x\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Big)\Big)$$

We see that one of the roots of $f(x)$ is very near to one (wich is our inequality).So we can apply [the Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) .

Remains to show that the function is decreasing around one and evaluate $\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Big)$.

Comment: the fixpoint is about 1.344, $a_{n+1} = \Gamma \left( \frac{a_n}{2} \right)$ alternates above and below the fixpoint, while getting a bit closer each time

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%280.5+x+%29+%3D+x

Comment: what is the origin of this problem? where did it come from?

Comment: @Arjang It's a problem found with the help of Wolfram alpha . On this site I have proposed some nested radicals so the idea is the same but with the Gamma function . There is a part of luck even if I know some digits of $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ .

Comment: @The.old.boy Looks curious $\Gamma(\frac12\Gamma(\frac12))<\frac{27}{25}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly,
$$\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2\approx 0.886.\tag1$$

Denote
$$y=\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\right),\tag2$$
then
$$y = \frac12\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}\right) < \frac12 + \gamma x + \left(\frac{\pi^2}6+\gamma^2-\gamma\right)x^2 + 0.251 x^3 + 2.33 x^4\tag3$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%CE%93%28%281-x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%29%20near%200) and [coefficients](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%CE%93%28%281-x-0.%29%2F%281%2Bx%2B0.%29%29%20near%200)),
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant,
$$x=\dfrac{2-\sqrt\pi}{2+\sqrt\pi}\approx0.060317809,\quad
\gamma\approx0.577215665.\tag4$$

The given inequality can be written in the form of
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma(y) < \dfrac{\pi\sqrt\pi}6\approx0.928054666,\tag5$$
wherein
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma(y) < 1 + \psi\left(\frac12\right)\left(y - \dfrac12\right) + \frac14\left(\pi^2+\psi^2\left(\frac12\right)\right)\left(y - \dfrac12\right)^2,\tag6$$
(see also [Wolfram alpha series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%CE%93%281%2F2%2By%29%2Fsqrt%20pi%20near%200) and [coefficients](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%CE%93%281%2F2%2By%2B0.%29%2Fsqrt%20pi%20near%200)),
where $\psi(x)$ is digamma function,
$$\psi\left(\frac12\right) = -\gamma - 2\ln2 \approx-1.963510026.\tag7$$

From $(3),(4)$ [should](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eulergamma%20x%20%281%20%2B%20%28eulergamma-1%29x%29%20%2Bx%5E2%28pi%5E2%2F6%2B0.251x%2B2.33x%5E2%29%2C%20where%20x%3D%282-sqrt%20pi%29%2F%282.%2Bsqrt%20pi%29)
$$y-\dfrac12 < \frac1{25}.\tag8$$

From $(6)-(8)$ should
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma(y) < 1 + \dfrac1{25}\psi\left(\frac12\right) + \dfrac1{2500}\left(\pi^2+\psi^2\left(\frac12\right)\right)\approx0.926949589
< \dfrac{\pi\sqrt\pi}6,$$
i.e. inequality $(5)$ is correct.

Therefore,
$$\color{brown}{\mathbf{\Gamma\left(\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12 \right)\right)\right) < \frac{\pi^2}6}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's nice .It shows that it's less difficult than expected .(+1)

Comment: @The.old.boy Thanks for the question, I was surprised how this puzzle has developed.